# Intro Math Matrices problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Find all $2 \times 2$ matrices $A= \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$ such that $AB= BA $ for all $2\times2 $ matrices B.

I am stumped as to how to approach this question overall. I am not sure if its asking for me to use some theorem or if some easier solution is present.

Comment: hint: Think about the identity matrix. $AB=BA$ implies $A$ commutes $B$. Can you name a $2\times 2$ matrix which commutes with every other matrix, i.e when you multiply with that matrix from the left or the right of any matrix $B$, the result remains same. Is there any other matrix with this property?

Comment: I was thinking the elementary matrix of I2x2 that might have this property. Am i on the right track?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let
$$A=\pmatrix{a&b\cr c&d\cr}$$
and suppose that $AB=BA$ for all $B$.  Making a particular choice for $B$ we have
$$\pmatrix{a&b\cr c&d\cr}\pmatrix{1&0\cr0&0\cr}
  =\pmatrix{1&0\cr0&0\cr}\pmatrix{a&b\cr c&d\cr}\ ,$$
so
$$\pmatrix{a&0\cr c&0\cr}=\pmatrix{a&b\cr0&0\cr}$$
which shows that $b=0$ and $c=0$.  Similarly,
$$\pmatrix{a&0\cr 0&d\cr}\pmatrix{0&1\cr0&0\cr}
  =\pmatrix{0&1\cr0&0\cr}\pmatrix{a&0\cr 0&d\cr}$$
gives $a=d$.  Therefore
$$A=\pmatrix{a&0\cr0&a\cr}=aI\ .$$
We have shown that these are the only possibilities for $A$.  This does not mean they actually work for all $B$, but it is easy to check that in fact they do.

Answer (score -2):

In General, matrix multiplication is not commutative.
AB = BA holds only in case if either A or B is an Identity Matrix, or B is the Inverse of A.

Comment: This is not correct. $B=A^2$ always commute with $A$, for instance.

Comment: With respect to that , so if I were to multiply A*B wouldn't that give me  a matrix like: a1=aB a2=bB b1=cB b2=dB ?

Comment: Good Point. So, the answer would be if A and B are simultaneously diagonalizable, they would be commutative.

Comment: @KingShahmoo is right